# Best name for a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm writing a simple Rails app and I'm wondering what to name a controller that creates accounts.

Some background: `Users` create a schedule and it's publicly visible. There are `users` and `events`. An `event` can have multiple `event_sessions`. That's pretty much it.

During registration a `user` is created, an `event` is created, and `sessions` are created. So where do I put this, the `UsersController`? And, if account creation includes all this other stuff, do I put it in a new controller? If so, what do I call the controller — `ExternalSiteController`? `AccountController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like the following, and tweak as necessary:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    # ...
    User.create(user_params)
    # ...
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :setup_initial_event
  has_many :events

  DEFAULT_EVENT_PARAMS = {
    # ...
  }

  def setup_initial_event
    events.create(DEFAULT_EVENT_PARAMS)
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :setup_initial_sessions
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sessions

  def setup_initial_sessions
    # You get the idea
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an `account` model (in which case `AccountsController` would be perfect), I'd put the code in the `UsersController`. `User` is probably the most complex and important model of the three (the registration of a `user` is what's kicking everything off, after all). Of course, you can create any object in any controller (i.e. you can call `User.create()` in the `EventsController`).